# SharePoint 2013: Rendition updated dimensions not picked up by browser

Tags: 2013, image-rendition

**Please read this before answering:** I know we can flush the BLOB cache and it will fix the problem.

But we're giving the power of updating the dimensions to end users and they might do it frequently. Flushing BLOB cache isn't the solution here.

We are using `https://sharepoint.com/PublishingImages/someImage.jpg?RenditionID=xx` to refer to the rendition image.

The browser cache is the problem here. How can we tell the browser to make sure it asks the server when the image dimensions are updated?

PS: I had a look at ImageRendition object and it does contain a Version property, but even if I change the dimensions it still remains 1.

Comment: how about appending another query string parameter, something like `.../someImage.jpg?RenditionID=xx&v=1.0` ?

Comment: But how would we know from server side that the dimensions have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up appending the last modified date of the Image library alongwith the RendtionID in the image URL.

So the URL becomes:

```
https://sharepoint.com/PublishingImages/someImage.jpg?RenditionID=xx&lastModified=xxxxxxxx
```

PS: The image item got modified but nothing obvious was changed in the properties, just a new version was created. Which in turn updates the last modified date of the image library.